# multithreading/processing in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

Hello I am trying  define values of a dictionary in parallel using multiprocessing.  When the function f() is called outside "pool" the dictionary value is set correctly.  In the pool call however it fails.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

hits={}
def f(x):
    hits[x] = x  #this will involve a complex operation

f('000')
print hits['000']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)             
    inputs = ['a','b','c']
    result = pool.map(f, inputs)
print hits['a']
```

Comment: Sharing state between processes is hard. Perhaps perform the complex operation in child processes and maintain the global state of `hits` in the parent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You spawn a bunch of subprocesses which inherit the current value of `hits`.  Each subprocess get its own copy of `hits` and modifies it, then exits, dropping the process-local copy of `hits`.

The intended use of `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` is to use its return value, which you are ignoring.  Each process could return its copy of `hits`, and you finally join these copies.

Comment: I see, then the answer is:                                                           from multiprocessing import Pool

hits={}
def f(x):
    return x
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=2)             
    inputs = ['a','b','c']
    result = pool.map(f, inputs)
result=dict(zip(result,result))

print result.items()